# How to get the value from a dropdown list and use it as a form submit id

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to yii so this may or may not make much sense. So I want to use on a form submit a dropdown list value as the id for cat_id.

Model:

```
public function getCategories(){

    $user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select()
        ->from('categories')
        ->queryAll();

    return $user;

}
```

This comes from the category model.

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Posts;
    $categories = Categories::model()->getCategories();
    $model->cat  = CHtml::listData($categories, 'id', 'name');

    if(isset($_POST['Posts']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Posts'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'categories'=>$model->cat,
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'cat_id'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('categories', $model, $model->cat, array('empty' => 'Select a category')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'cat_id'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Posts;

    if(isset($_POST['Posts']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Posts'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

View as

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'cat_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'cat_id',CHtml::listData(Categories::model()->findAll(),'id','name'),array('empty' => 'Select a category')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'cat_id'); ?>
</div>
```